# Удалённая отладка в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-xp, virtualbox, c++, windows-8

Доброго времени суток, участники форума!
Описываю ситуацию. Есть операционная система Windows 8.1. На ней стоит Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. Так же, на операционке стоит Virtual Box последней версии с созданной виртуальной машиной Windows XP. Очень хочется отлаживать созданное на родительской операционке приложение (на языке С++), как будто программа работает с гостевой ОС. Это вроде как называется Remote Debugging. Прошу написать подробную инструкцию, как это можно сделать.
Заранее огромное спасибо всем, кто откликнется.

Comment: @Kristya, как видно из истории изменений Вашего вопроса, эта тема мало кому интересна (особенно в смысле написания подробных инструкций).

Наверное в сети они уже есть. Похоже, [вот эта](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/bt727f1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), найденная через гугл, одна из них.

Comment: @avp, Спасибо, ну хоть кто-то ответил!))) А то я уж подумала, что просто никто не знает ответа на этот вопрос!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут ещё видюшка, в которой всё хорошо видно, как отладку делать:
     [Remote Debugging with Visual Studio 2008](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEp6VqUg2WE)